# Change color from a Rectangle using a TColorListBox

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey, shapes, c++builder-xe6

I'm here again.
I just would like to discover how to change the color background of a rectangle (Shape) using a TColorListBox.
I know it is easy, however I'm getting exception all the time I try to set a new value for the Rectangle.
The command I'm using is the following:

```
Rectangle1->Fill->Color = ColorListBox1->Color;
```

Function:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ColorListBox1Click(const TCustomListBox *Sender,
          const TListBoxItem *Item)
{
    Rectangle1->Fill->Color = ColorListBox1->Color;
}
```

Now the error I'm getting all the time I try to change the collor:

```
Access violation at address 00405628 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 00000360.
```

Another exception on debugger is here:

```
First chance exception at $00405615. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00405615: read of address 0x00000360'. Process Ninterpres.exe (904)
```

Could someone help me please?Since now, thanks A LOT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem...
The access violation code is because of multiple pointers with the same name.
On this case I was using Rectangle1 (Actually is was called Transp, I changed the name to put here to make the comprehension easier) as a int var and as an object...
Thanks for the answers XD.

Answer (score 1):

First time You wrote

```
ColorListBox1
```

and second time You used name without '1'

```
ColorListBox->Color;
```

But it looks like You have not initialised some object (as i remember this shall be done automagically by Form Editor) thus program throws an exception.

Comment: Sorry, I had passed the wrong name (they were with portuguese names, but were the same in the two cases)...
I'll try the workaround I've found at docwiki from Embarcadero:
` if (Ellipse1->Fill->Kind == TBrushKind::Solid)
  Ellipse1->Fill->Color = ColorListBox1->Color;
 else
  Ellipse1->Fill->Gradient->Color = ColorListBox1->Color;`